# How to use SARIMA forecasting when some of the data has strong outliers?

Tags: python, forecasting, arima

I am using the SARIMA approach to forecast a large set (~10 000) of time series. In Python the `pyramid` module provides the `auto_arima` that can be used like this

```
from pyramid.arima import auto_arima

stepwise_model = auto_arima(train, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                           max_p=3, max_q=3, m=12,
                           start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                           d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                           error_action='ignore',  
                           suppress_warnings=True, 
                           stepwise=True)

stepwise_model.fit(train)

future_forecast = stepwise_model.predict(n_periods=test.shape[0])
```

For some time series this works quite nicely, like for this one:

[image: Time series forecasting working nicely]

However some of the time series are not really "forecastable" and thus the SARIMA approach is not working:

[image: Failed forecasting]

What would be a strategy to either distinguish between "forecastable" and "unforecastable" data and only use the SARIMA algorithm on the first group or to modify the SARIMA algorithm to improve the forecasting?

Comment: [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37525/anomaly-detection-on-time-series) is a question specifically dealing with outlier detection, some of the mentioned resources may be a good place to start

Comment: So the idea would be to use k-means to categorize the time series into different sets and then use SARIMA only on some of those sets and other techniques for other sets?

Comment: That sort of ensemble method is one approach, depending on your application and intent. Other options I've seen are to drop outliers completely over a certain threshold, or to apply moving window-averaging to smooth the outliers, or other k-nearest neighbors-type algorithms to overwrite them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I figured maybe outlier was the wrong term to use. Those peaks are actual real occurences. However as can be seen, the ARIMA approach fails miserably for those time series were rarely anything happens. So what I think I need to do is to divide the complete set into two sets: one with "regular" data as in the first graph and one with all the data sets that look the the second one. Then I would treat those differently, for example here it looks like the event happens every 3 years. I was wondering if there are tools for handling this kind of data.

Comment: I'd say it's an outlier if you're trying to predict the line, but if you're actually trying to predict the spikes, then that would be the target of your analysis. Either way, it sounds like you're on the right track with defining 2 different problems

Comment: Nearest neaighbor dynamic time warp is one tool I've seen used, but I know it can be tricky. [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/dynamic-time-warping-is-outdated) is an extended discussion on it. I've seen citations from [this](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=3132847.3132964) paper before, but haven't read it myself

Comment: One more question: On what properties would I do the categorization? Is there some calculatable value that distinguishes the two time series that I plotted?

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody can really help with that without seeing the underlying data the plots are drawn from. If it were me, I'd be using outlier/anomaly detection algorithms to try to determine the underlying causes for the spikes, then try to find the pattern and predict `is_spike==1` or `is_spike==0`